# Find and match data from a column - email address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I extracted data from two different AD domains to a CSV.  The headers are Name, samAccountName1, samAccountName2, mail1, mail2.  I need to match mail1 against mail2.  mail1 has 1372 rows of data, mail2 has 60157 rows of data.  The rows for mail1 & mail2 do not match up of course.. they are unsorted.  How can I find or lookup the matches from the mail1 column to the mail2 column and perhaps sort the data?

Thank you

Comment: Is not clear what you want to do "sort", "match"? What is your desired output? Do you want to consolidate / merge the lists? Some sample data might help too.

Comment: Do all mail1 values exist in mail2? Do both columns have values in the same row? Or does either mail1 OR mail2 contain values? Are you only interested in the ones where mail1 has a match in mail2? More detail please, we can't look inside your head. A data sample and the desired result mocked up would help.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What steps did you carry out to create the CSV file? (We have many Windows admin tools that create CSVs from AD.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper column that you populate with this formula (assuming mail1 is column D, mail2 is column E and first row of data is in row 2, with row 1 having labels):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D:D,E2),E2,IF(COUNTIF(E:E,D2),D2,""))
```

This column now has the email addresses that exist in both lists. You can now sort or filter on the helper column

[image]